# How to unpin docklets in ubuntu mate 20.04

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-mate, dock, plank

I tried to use the battery and CPU monitor dock-let, just for curiosity... Once I had done it, I wasn't able to remove it, I have seen other such questions but the solutions didn't help me, I use Ubuntu mate 20.04 and dragging and dropping the dock-let outside doesn't work...
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried doing right mouse click on the application icon in the Plank dock and then uncheck "Keep in Dock"?